# How to check if String contains a letter\sign in multiple places via PowerShell?

Tags: regex, string, powershell

I am trying to check if given word contains '#' sign in multiple places that are not joined together.
For example:
`$word1 = "Contains#Signs#Not#Joined"`  does contain what I am looking for
But: `$word2 = "Contains###OnlyJoinedSigns"` this string contains only signs that are joined.

I want to return `$false` if I find signs that are not joined together.
I tried using:
`if($computerNameToGenerate -like "*#*#*") { return $false}` but it's not working as I want.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following Regex:

```
$word1 = "Contains#Signs#Not#Joined"
$word1 -match "#[^#]+#"
```

The hat specifies excluding hash, the plus signifies at least one (non-hash) character.